# Работа с классами Python

Tags: python, база-данных, orm, peewee

Есть вот такой код, который подключается к БД

```
    ######################## ИНИЦИАЛИЗАЦИЯ DB ########################
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = MySQLDatabase('base.db')

    def close_connection(self):
        self.conn.close()

    ######################## БАЗОВАЯ МОДЕЛЬ ########################
    class BaseModel(Model):
        class Meta():
            database = conn
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю, как подключить класс Meta() к классу MySQL_ORM() и оттуда взять conn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал через небольшой костыль, вроде бы работает

```
    def __init__(self,database='base.db'):
        self.database = database

    ######################## DB ИНИЦИАЛИЗАЦИЯ ########################
    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = MySQLDatabase(self.database)

    def close_connection(self):
        self.conn.close()

class MyORM(MySQL):
    ######################## БАЗОВАЯ МОДЕЛЬ ########################
    class BaseModel(Model):
        class Meta(MySQL):
            database = MySQL().create_connection()
```